# WinUI 3 - shell interop vs MS Store ecommerce privileges

Tags: winforms, winapi, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

Considering the sandboxing factor, and OTH that MS appears to be giving renewed attention to the value of desktop in the aftermath of UWP/Win 8 failings, could a WinUI 3 app, granted some level of trust below corporate/institutional, be permitted to do IPC with a win32 explorer shell extension
AND
have all components, extension dll included, packaged in such a way that it may be a Store app
AND
participate in native Store ecommerce thus not have to be
kicked out into the cold of 3rd party payment/registration processing for the customer to buy the app (after a trial period etc)?

follow-on question.  Then is there some intrinsic security reason that MS would be prevented from offering Store payment API/services to anything but sandboxed applications or those with a level of corporate/institutional trust?  Or maybe just not a priority?

thanks

Comment: There shouldn't be any upfront limitation any more https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/desktop-apps

Comment: With WinUI 3 having dropped support for UWP altogether, there doesn't appear to be a whole lot of sandboxing going on with WinUI 3 applications. WinUI 3 applications are just Desktop applications with an app identity. I'm guessing (but haven't verified) that app identity is the only prerequisite for using types in the [`Windows.Services.Store`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store) namespace.

Comment: >Simon  saw an earlier version of that article back in spring when it had a date stamp of June '20 ?, and they've added some customer testimonials.

once a caveat, now a feature, lol, one must (still) bring their own ecommerce and CDN for what is (abridged)

"commonly called “Win32” apps, packaged in .EXE, .MSI installers, built using .NET (WPF, Forms, console) to C++, WinUI, MFC......to be part of the WS catalog"

I'll assume here WinUI means WinUI, but


still not sure where WinUI 3 falls if I have a shell DLL in the package. 

A cut for MS, in my case, fine with that.

Comment: >IInspectable
I'm still just going to have to dig into the fine print, IF I can find it.
And may do a Hello World with the essential features that might be the hangup in terms of getting to use the store services namespace, then see if I can buy my Hello World from the store in their simulation sandbox thing.